# Tomcat response time spikes

Tags: garbage-collection, tomcat7, threadpool, java-7, newrelic

I am facing a performance issue in my web app with respect to average response time.

My stack is

Oracle Java 7
Tomcat 7.62/61
AWS Linux box 
Java opts -Xms1G -Xmx4G -XParallelGCThreads=4 (not complete will add more)
Using new relic

From my web app, I am calling other service (another Java process on different machine)

I am using Executors.newCachedThreadPool() (I know it's bad, but can't attribute my issue to this thing only yet) to call the other process on rest.

Now to the question, my new relic shows spike for web app average response time every 15-20 minutes or so. Thread count do increase at that time. (Only visible thing) CPU however doesn't increase alarmingly. Only marginal spike, and stays under 50. GC is running regularly, though I don't have time.(new relic shows only GC collection %age)

On service side, average response time never increases, stays more or less flat during spike.

Drilling down on webap call shows increased time for those service though in external service (feels like a discrepancy to me between two applications stats on new relic any idea?)

1. Can somebody suggest approach to solve the problem?
2. What more data should I collect to go about it?
3. Can somebody throw light on new relic missing dots?
4. Is it GC or the thread pool from the look of it?

Answer (score 0):

To identify GC issues: enable GC logging for example and run the resulting file through [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer)

To identify long-running tasks on the thread pool: Attach a profiler and then look at thread histories to see whether threads of the executor pool are constantly busy or have some idle time

Answer (score 0):

you should try G1 GC . It will shorten long gc and hence spike